# Eye Chart Lighting for Consistency?

Tags: eye, eye-exam

If the goal is consistent test results and controlling for distance is a given, then would a backlight in a dark/darkened room guarantee the most consistent results?

Is there any other way to control for consistent light conditions when moving eye-test equipment from room to room?

Would a screen produce consistent results as well, as long as letter size was controlled?

The goal, obviously, is measuring visual acuity accurately.

Comment: What are you testing with an eye chart?

Comment: Visual acuity. I.e. how near-sighted/far-sighted a person is. Nothing unusual, this is for an experiment, and obviously I am not an optometrist.

Comment: But you're testing under darkness which isn't how we mainly use our eyes.

Comment: Assuming you want test results as close to what an optometrist would obtain then normal fluorescent office lighting would be the best choice.